# Primes of the form $x^2 + n y^2$ using theta function

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions, theta-functions

It is well known that if $p$ is a prime, then $p$ can be written in the form $x^2 + n y^2$ under certain congruences conditions. For example,

\begin{align}
p = x^2+y^2 &\Leftrightarrow p = 2 \text{ or } p = 1 \text{ }(\mathrm{mod}\text{ }4) \\
p = x^2+2y^2 &\Leftrightarrow p = 2 \text{ or } p = 1,3 \text{ }(\mathrm{mod}\text{ }8) \\
p = x^2+3y^2 &\Leftrightarrow p = 3 \text{ or } p = 1 \text{ }(\mathrm{mod}\text{ }3)
\end{align}

At the same time, one can constructs a generating function for the number of solutions of the equation $x^2 + n y^2 = m$, using the theta function. If one define,

\begin{equation}
\phi(q) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty q^{m^2}
\end{equation}

Then, we have the following generating function,

\begin{equation}
\phi(q)\phi(q^n) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty q^m \text{ nb_solutions}(x^2 + n y^2 = m) 
\end{equation}

**Question :**

I do wonder whether it is possible to **demonstrate the congruences above using an analytical method** through the generating function written above, and the identities of the theta function. This would for example imply verifying that the coefficient is zero for primes satisfying a certain congruence, and verifying it is not for others.

**Note :**

Being a physics student, I would be really pleased by a solution which only involves symbolic manipulations, and identites of the theta function. I do not understand high mathematical theories concerning modular forms, elliptic functions or whatever. I have come to understand such things only by playing with it alone, and finding some information on the internet.

Comment: Some thoughts : In the case $n = 1$, this problem is equivalent to demonstrating that the $p$ th derivative $$ (\phi^2)^{(p)}(0) = 0 $$ when $p = 4k + 3$ and $$ (\phi^2)^{(p)}(0) \neq 0 $$ when $p = 4k + 1$

Comment: I think that the OEIS entries for sequences [A004018](https://oeis.org/A004018), [A033715](https://oeis.org/A033715), [A033716](https://oeis.org/A033716) for $n=1,2,3$ respectively may give you some ideas.

Comment: A possible method may be to compute by force the pth derivative of the generating function. We may be able to obtain an infinite serie, which is equal to zero for $p = 4k + 3$ and not for $p = 4k + 1$. However, I am not strong enough to compute the nth derivative of an infinite product, and even if I was, I suspect that such serie may be impracticable.

Comment: The congruences are expressed naturally on the Dirichlet series side (product of $\zeta(s)$ and a Dirichlet L-function) not on the theta function side. Connecting the two is called quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: The subject is deep and fascinating so much so that there is a book *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$* by David Cox.

Comment: The first congruence goes by name Fermat's little theorem and it can be handled using theta functions via identity $$\phi^2(q)=1+4\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{q^n} {1+q^{2n}}$$ See details at https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-fourier-series.html?m=0

Comment: The last congruence can probably be handled using the identity $$\phi(q)\phi(q^{3}) = 1 + 2\left(\frac{q}{1 - q} - \frac{q^{2}}{1 + q^{2}} + \frac{q^{4}}{1 + q^{4}} - \frac{q^{5}}{1 - q^{5}} + \cdots\right)$$ but I haven't checked yet.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for your comment. I have been able to figure the $x^2 + y^2 = n$ congruences using your comment and your blog post. As for the identity for $\phi(q)\phi(q^3)$, could you explicitly specify the pattern in the summation, for I am not sure how does the sum continues. Do you plan to write a full answer ?

Comment: The series in last comment can be written as $$\phi(q)\phi(q^{3}) = 1 + 2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{q^{6n + 1}}{1 - q^{6n + 1}} - \frac{q^{6n + 2}}{1 + q^{6n + 2}} + \frac{q^{6n + 4}}{1 + q^{6n + 4}} - \frac{q^{6n + 5}}{1 - q^{6n + 5}}\right)$$ I haven't done the needed calculations for this series so can't really write an answer. Further I also need to check what can be done for $\phi(q) \phi(q^2)$ (second congruence).